# How do I store my websites header and footer in one location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, footer

I am always rewriting my headers and footers and for every edit i have to manually copy and paste all the code into the web pages. Obviously this is the wrong approach but im not sure of the right one. My current idea is to have a "header" and "footer" div and then with jquery's $(document).ready load the divs with code. Im afraid it will be slow though because it waits for the whole page to render before executing the header/footer code. What is a common way to handle this problem?

Comment: is there no way for some kind of server side code, like PHP? Otherwise your site will not be accessible with javascript disabled.

Comment: I can use php but im still not sure of the optimum solution. I mean if i have site-a.php site-b.php site-c.php I will still have to copy and paste the code in. Perhaps all three can read from a single file ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you need some server-side technology. Which one (of the many options) you choose is up to you and your hosting. Most likely, your hosting will support PHP and SSI (Server-side includes).

In the simplest setup, basically put the common code into individual files, let's say `header.inc` and `footer.inc`. It doesn't matter what the name or extension of these files are.

For PHP, your pages should now be `*.php` instead of `*.html` and you need to write this code:

```
<?php include('header.inc'); ?>
<p>
    Here is your regular document.
</p>
<?php include('footer.inc'); ?>
```

For SSI, you don't have to change the names of your files, and your code would look like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="header.inc" -->
<p>
    Here is your regular document.
</p>
<!--#include virtual="footer.inc" -->
```

Answer (score 4):

You definitely don't want to do this with Javascript. First off, the header and footer won't load until the Javascript executes, but more important, anyone without Javascript enabled won't see them at all (and requiring Javascript to view a static page doesn't make sense).

There are two easy methods to do this:

1) Use a server-side language like php to include the footers:

```
<?php
  include('header.html');
?>
The rest of the page goes here
<?php
  include('footer.html');
?>
```

2) Use a build/deploy process that generates static pages. This would be similar to 1) but it would only be done once per build, rather than every time someone hits the page.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly, there's some server-side templating technology in use, such as PHP, JSP or XSL.  Creating reusable pieces of code which can be linked is fairly simple using one of these approaches.

For a pure HTML + JS approach, you could use an IFRAME to link to a standalone header and footer HTML file.  That would allow you to keep all the header and footer information in one place, only needing to update it once.

Answer (score 0):

Common way is to use server side language like [PHP](http://php.net). Or if you need only footer and header include you can use [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML or PHP includes.